# Why does the Split type only return &str even though Pattern has implementations for both &str and char?

Tags: generics, rust, iterator, traits, associated-types

I'm having a hard time understanding how the `Split` type works in Rust.

`Split<'a, P> where P: Pattern<'a>` is the type returned by the [`std::string::String::split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.split) method. The type has an implementation for `Iterator<'a, P>`, where `P` is still the `Pattern` type, but in reality (and as I would expect) the `Iterator` only returns `&str` slices.

E.g., `split(p).collect::<Vec<&str>>()` works but `split(p).collect::<Vec<char>>()` results a compiler error. This is what I would expect to happen, but I don't understand how it happens since `Pattern` has implementations for both `&str` and `char`.

Why isn't the `Split` type simply defined as `Split<'a, &'a str>`, since it is effectively an `Iterator` over `&str`s? Why does it behave as if it is effectively defined as that?

Comment: The output type of an Iterator is not it's type parameter, but rather its `Item` associated type.

Comment: You confuse the generic parameter of the `Iterator` (`P`) with its `Item` associated type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The type has an implementation for `Iterator<'a, P>`

It doesn't. It's just `Iterator`, which has no type parameters. Every implementation of `Iterator` must declare the type of the item that it iterates over using an associated type. For example, `Split`'s implementation<sup>[1]</sup> is something like this:

```
impl <'a, P> Iterator for Split<'a, P> {
    type Item = &'a str;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a str> { ... }
}
```

> Why isn't the `Split` type simply defined as `Split<'a, &'a str>`, since it is effectively an `Iterator` over `&str`s?

Because iterators are lazy. The `Split` struct still needs to know about the pattern in order to match the next item. Its iterator instance has `Item = &str`, because that is what it iterates over.

---

*<sup>[1]</sup>The actual implementation is [generated by a macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#957-964).*